# Axiom schema of replacement/specification(separation) as second-order

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

A question to check whether my confusion is correctly removed: how would axiom schema of replacement and specification be written in second-order?

By the way, I know that second-order logic is not reducible to first-order logic, and those matters are irrelevant to this question. Just provide me how these axiom schema would be written as second-order and I would really, really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement axiom as second-order would be something like this:

$$\begin{align}
\forall F\forall p_1\ldots\forall p_n\forall A(&\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow\exists y(F(x,y,p_1,\ldots,p_n)\land\forall z(F(x,z,p_1,\ldots,p_n)\rightarrow z=y))\rightarrow\\
&\exists B\forall u(u\in B\leftrightarrow\exists v(v\in A\land F(v,u)))
\end{align}$$

We say that for every $F$ which defines a function (up to parameters $p_i$'s) on a set $A$, there is a set $B$ which is the image of $A$ under the function $F$ (with the parameters $p_i$).

The difference between the first-order schema and second-order axiom is that $F$ quantifies over *all* classes, even those not defined by a formula. The result is that we have a single axiom, instead of "a lot of them".

Note however, that second-order relies on the notion of a set to be well-defined so doing second-order set theory is a bit... awkward because usually define sets as objects in a universe of set theory, and this causes a bit of circularity.

---

This is somewhat similar to the difference between first-order and second-order induction in Peano Axioms, you can read some about this in here: [Axiom schema and the definition of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79536/622)

Comment: Thanks, Asaf. Now my confusion is all cleared :)